# How to open scraped links one by one automatically using Python?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, automation, ebay-api

So here is my situation: Let's say you search on eBay for "Motorola DynaTAC 8000x". The bot that I build is going to scrape all the links of the listings. My goal is now, to make it open those scraped links one by one.

I think something like that would be possible with using loops, but I am not sure on how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code of the bot:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=Motorola+DynaTAC+8000x&_sacat=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.select("li a")

for a in listings:
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/"):
        print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get information from the `link` you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=Motorola+DynaTAC+8000x&_sacat=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.select("li a")

for a in listings:
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/"):
        s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
        price = s.select_one('[itemprop="price"]')

        print(s.h1.text)
        print(price.text if price else "-")
        print(link)
        print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

Details about   MOTOROLA DYNATAC 8100L- BRICK CELL PHONE VINTAGE RETRO RARE MUSEUM 8000X
GBP 555.00
https://www.ebay.com/itm/393245721991?hash=item5b8f458587:g:c7wAAOSw4YdgdvBt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Details about   MOTOROLA DYNATAC 8100L- BRICK CELL PHONE VINTAGE RETRO RARE MUSEUM 8000X
GBP 555.00
https://www.ebay.com/itm/393245721991?hash=item5b8f458587:g:c7wAAOSw4YdgdvBt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Details about   Vintage Pulsar  Extra Thick Brick Cell Phone Has Dynatac 8000X Display
US $3,000.00
https://www.ebay.com/itm/163814682288?hash=item26241daeb0:g:sTcAAOSw6QJdUQOX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```